# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE string to replace 'n' times starting with nn position

Tags: string, oracle, oracle19c

I want to replace '|' with '_'.  The replacement should start from nnth character and replace n times.  For e.g.

```
ABC|1234|mno|p|q|r|456|XYZ|QRS|TUV ====> ABC|1234|mno|p_q_r|456|XYZ|QRS|TUV
```

In above example nn=14 and n=3

So far, I've tried this but not getting the expected results

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC|1234|mno|p|q|r|456|XYZ', '[|]', '_',14) rep_str FROM DUAL
```

Comment: There is no "number of replacements" argument. So, it can look like `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC|1234|mno|p|q|r|456|XYZ', '\|', '_', 14, 1),'\|', '_', 14, 1),'\|', '_', 14, 1)  rep_str FROM DUAL`

Comment: If n is 3, why do you get `p_q_r|456` rather than `p_q_r_456`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple example it's easier to specify both 2 occurences:

```sql
  regexp_replace(
      str
     , '\|([^|]+)'
     ||'\|([^|]+)' -- 2 times just to make it more readable
     ||'(.*)'      --  others
     ,'_\1_\2\3'
     ,14
  )
```

Full example with test data: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=198eb0115a97c8dc8716104be479f11f)

```sql
with t as (
select
  'ABC|1234|mno|p|q|r|456|XYZ|QRS|TUV' str
 ,'ABC|1234|mno|p_q_r|456|XYZ|QRS|TUV' chk 
from dual
)
select
  str,chk,
  regexp_replace(
      str
     , '\|([^|]+)'
     ||'\|([^|]+)' -- 2 times just to make it more readable
     ||'(.*)'      --  others
     ,'_\1_\2\3'
     ,14
  ) as str2
from t
/
```

Or if you make it more customizable and specify number of replacement easier, you can use simple inline pl/sql function with a loop like this: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d0e9792d0d6939b4bd5f545d93238511)

```sql
with function regexp_replaces(
    source_char  varchar2
   ,pattern      varchar2
   ,replace_char varchar2
   ,position     int
   ,cnt          int
  ) return varchar2
as
  res varchar2(4000):=source_char;
begin
  for i in 1..cnt loop
    res:=regexp_replace(res,pattern,replace_char,position,1);
  end loop;
  return res;
end;
select
  str,chk,
  regexp_replaces(str,'\|','_',14,2) as str2
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with plain `substr`/`instr`, but need to process edge cases carefully. Extract the part you need and replace all pipes in it. Then put everything together back.

> ```
> with
> --
> function replace_n(
>   str in varchar2,
>   start_ in number,
>   count_ in number
> )
> return varchar2
> as
> begin
>   return
>     /*Starting part unchanged*/
>     substr(str, 1, start_)
>     /*Replacement: locate n'th - 1 occurrence of pipe*/
>     || translate(
>       substr(str, start_ + 1, instr(str, '|', start_, count_-1) - start_)
>       , '|'
>       , '_'
>     )
>     /*Remaining string*/
>     || substr(str, instr(str, '|', start_, count_ - 1) + 1)
>   ;
> end;
> --
> a(a) as (
>   select
>   'ABC|1234|mno|p|q|r|456|XYZ|QRS|TUV'
>   from dual
> )
>
> select replace_n(a, 14, 3) as res
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> | RES                                |
> | :--------------------------------- |
> | ABC|1234|mno|p_q_r|456|XYZ|QRS|TUV |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4f0e703afde3179a3ebc6e6a97418a17)*

**UPD**: Or if you were about replacement in the substring of size `n` starting from position `nnn`:

> ```
> with
> --
> function replace_n(
>   str in varchar2,
>   start_ in number,
>   count_ in number
> )
> return varchar2
> as
> begin
>   return
>     /*Starting part unchanged*/
>     substr(str, 1, start_)
>     /*Replacement: extract substring on size n*/
>     || translate(
>       substr(str, start_ + 1, instr(str, '|', start_, count_-1) - start_)
>       , '|'
>       , '_'
>     )
>     /*Remaining string*/
>     || substr(str, instr(str, '|', start_, count_ - 1) + 1)
>   ;
> end;
> --
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8b318f06e01b167915cbc6bb983cf5ed)*

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.  I'm bit surprized that REGEX_REPLACE does not support replacing just 'n' number of replacements